# How to pass data attribute into function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are several `a` elements

```
<a class="gift-info" data-giftid="1" ...
<a class="gift-info" data-giftid="12" ...
<a class="gift-info" data-giftid="99" ...
```

How to get `data-giftid` attribute and pass the value into a function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.gift-info").click(function(){
        // how to pass data-giftid value into infoHide() function?
        var _id= ...
        infoHide(_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: `var _id= $(this).data('giftid');`

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-giftid')`

Comment: Or... `this.getAttribute('data-giftid')` - I think that covers it.   Or you could do:  `this.outerHTML.match(/(data-giftid=")(.*?)(")/g)[1]`.   Some may consider that last approach inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $ele = $("a.gift-info");
  $.each($ele,function(index,element){
    element.click(function(){
        // how to pass data-giftid value into infoHide() function?
        var _id= $(this).attr('data-giftid')
        infoHide(_id);
    });
  
  }):
    
});
```